# How can I calculate missing values from a table listing of areas and prices?

Tags: linear-transformations, mathematical-modeling, estimation

I have a set of objects of different sizes (measured in square metres). I know the price of some of them. I want to use the known prices to find the missing prices.

Here is the data I have:

\begin{array}{c c}
0.13 m^2  & 7500\\
0.13 m^2 & 7500\\
0.15 m^2 & ?\\
0.20 m^2  & ?\\
0.20 m^2 & ?\\
0.40 m^2 & ?\\
0.65 m^2 & ?\\
1.03 m^2  & ?\\
1.18 m^2 & 15000
\end{array}

I have tried this function:

$a=$size $b=$min price $c=$min size $d=$max size

$x= a-c$; $y = (a*100/d)*x$; $w = b*y/100$; $z= b+w$

Comment: What is "mt"? A unit? In American notation, are those numbers $0.13$ and $1.18$; i.e. are those decimal commas? And what kind of formula are you looking for: a linear one? That is not quite "in proportion", which is not possible in your problem, but it is close.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I've edited this question for the questioner. Can you consider opening it?

Comment: You answered all my questions except the comma. I'll assume that it is a decimal comma and will vote to reopen this question.

Comment: I've edited the commas - they are meant to be decimal points. In the UK we use a "." rather than "," but in France they use "," so I'm accustomed to seeing both notations.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have two objects with a "dimension" of $0.13$ mt (metres?) that have a price of $7500$, you have one object with a dimension of $1.18$ mt that has a price of $15000$ and you have other objects with known dimension but no known price.

You would like to find a formula for price based on dimension.

Let the dimension be $x$.

You want to find a function for the price: $p(x)$

You will need to decide on the type of function you want to to have.

Possible candidate functions include:

Linear: $p(x)=ax+b$

Exponential: $p(x)=ka^x$

Power: $p(x)=kx^a$

These have two parameters which can be estimated from the two data points you have.

Other candidates might be more complicated and would therefore need either more data or more information about the function.

For example, quadratic: $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

---

If you want a linear function, then the gradient $a = \frac {15000 - 7500}{1.18 - 0.13}=\frac {7500}{1.05} =\frac {50000}{7}$.

Substituting the known value $p(0.13)=7500$ gives:

$\frac {50000}{7} \times 0.13 + b = 7500$

$6500+7b = 52500$

$7b = 46000$

$b = \frac {46000} 7$

$p(x)=\frac {50000}{7}x + \frac {46000} 7$

$p(x)=\frac {50000x + 46000} 7$

Comment: yes you have undestand right, the dimension is in sqm (square meters), i have write two time 0,13 why i have 50 objects and several have the same size. i think linear can be good for my problem, i have try this fuction:
a=size
b=min price
c=min size
d=max size
x= a-c;
y = (a*100/d)*x;
w = b*y/100;
z= b+w;